# Power loss in a chilling pipe

Tags: thermodynamics

I am calculating the loss power of a chilling pipe. The system has a fluid flow in with a temperature $T_{in}$ and constant speed $v$, then flowing out the system, and some high temperature $T_{bnd}$ boundary condition outside the pipe. Since the calculation is complicated, I have to use software to do the simulation.

Then when the system reaches to a stationary state, I got the temperature distribution $T(r,z)$ (in cylindrical coordinates), heat capacity $C_{P} [J/(kg\cdot K)]$ (assume it does not change with temperature), the density of the chilling fluid $\rho$.

I want to calculate how much power of heat was transferred from outside of the system. I assume an isothermal system without heat transfer outside minus the system I simulated.
Since $C_{P}=\frac{dQ}{MdT}$,
$$ Q =\int_{V} C_p\Delta T \rho dV = \int_{V} C_p(T(r,z)-T_{in}) \rho dV$$
So basically, I realize that I calculate the heat change from isothermal system to the simulated result system. However, I want to calculate the power of heat transfer $P$ between inside and outside pipe, but my result is just the heat and seems to have nothing to do with the power.

I couldn't figure out a way to calculate the power, I wish someone can give me some ideas. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated the rate of heat transfer incorrectly.  Since the pipe is operating at steady state, the internal energy within the system is constant.  The correct equation for the rate of heat transfer involves the change in enthalpy between inlet and outlet:  $$Q=\int_0^R{2\pi rv(r)\rho C_p(T-T_{in})dr}$$ where v(r) is the fluid velocity at radial position r, and the integral is evaluated at the pipe exit.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense to me now.